# I have the following yaml specification:

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

How to order FilterFactory

```
spring:
  cloud:
   gateway:
    routes:
    - id: test
      uri: http://httpbin.org:80
      predicates:
      - Path=/test/**
      filters:
      - name: RewritePath
        regexp: /test/(?<segment>.*) 
        replacement: /$\{segment}
```

But I also have my own custom filter

```
public class MyGlobalFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
```

which allows me to specify order.
I don't know two things:  What is the order number of the FilterFactory RewritePath?  How can I trigger it to come before or after my own MyGlobalFilter?

Answer (score 0):

(1)The filters defined in 'gateway.routes' are automatically ordered from 1 if they have no order.
(2)You can define an ordered GlobalFilter or an OrderedGatewayFilterFactory with the inner GatewayFilterFactory.